# Escaping HTML in jQuery so it's valid

Tags: jquery, html, validation, xhtml

I've followed advice from firebug and W3C links, however when Firebug confirms all is valid, W3C does not seem to like it and vice versa.

All I'm doing is this:

```
return '<a href="#"></a>';
```

I believe I should use a backslash infront of the forward slash, though as XHTML, the start tag needs to be escaped as well? Can anyone shed any light on this.

Thanks.

Comment: It's for jQuery Cycle plugin, returning the html for the pager.

Comment: I've got it down to 1 error on W3C. `code`return '\<a href="#">\</a>';

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: [Don't use XHTML on the client](http://dorward.me.uk/tmp/xhtml/msiexhtml.png).

Almost the short answer: [Put your JavaScript in external files](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_4)

Longer answer: If you really want to embed the JS, then [wrap it with CDATA flags](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_4)

Really long answer: Read http://dorward.me.uk/www/comments-cdata/

Comment: Thanks. The really long answer is top.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap JS in CDATA tags, you don't need to escape the HTML.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
function(){
    return '<a href="#"></a>';
};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```